# How to record and access teams meeting audio?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have used MS Graph API to schedule an online meeting. Now, I want to access audio or transcript of the meeting for some further processing. What are the possible ways for this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! In its current form, your question is not a great fit for SO: we like to help people who run into technical issues while trying to build something. Looking for an API isn't necessarily that. Please have a look at [ask].

Comment: Currently we do not have any Graph API to access the transcription from Teams meeting.
You can raise a user voice here:  https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/filters/new

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @ChetanSharma-msft, currently **Teams do not have any
Graph API to access the meeting transcript**

You can send your feedback about this here: [Microsoft Teams · Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)